# I want to direct the onClick event of a button in Reactjs to some another page. How do I do it?

Tags: reactjs

This is my Home.js where I have two buttons- "Maker" and "Designer".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Designer from './Designer';
import Maker from './Maker';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Jumbotron';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import SignOut from './SignOut';
import history from './../history';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.designer = this.designer.bind(this);
        this.maker = this.maker.bind(this);
    }
    designer() {
        return(
            <Designer></Designer>
        );
    }
    maker() {
        return(
            <Maker></Maker>
        );
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Col>
                <Row>
                    <Button variant="dark" onClick={this.designer}>Designer</Button>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Button variant="dark" onClick ={this.maker}>Maker</Button>
                </Row>
            </Col>

        );
    }



}

export default Home;
```

Now, I want to to direct the onClick button to a new page. How do I do that? I thought of using

```
designer() {
        return(
            <Designer></Designer>
        );
    }
```

So, I made Designer.js

```
 import React from 'react';

    function Designer(){
    return(
        alert("Hello")
    );
}


export default Designer;
```

But when I click on the button Designer, I don't see the alert box. 
Actually, I need a new page when the button is clicked and on that page I need a form which has a set of questions and the user has to answer it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do.

1. Create `history.js` file where you create a new [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) object.

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

   export default createBrowserHistory();
   ```
2. Add [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) and add **routing** to your application in order to create new pages.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import history from './history.js'

   import {
    Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
    } from "react-router-dom";

   export default function App() {
     return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
         <Switch>
          <Route path="/designer" component={Designers} /> // PATH FOR DESIGNER PAGE

          <Route path="/maker" component={Makers} /> // PATH FOR MAKER PAGE

          <Route path="/" component={Home} />

          </Route>
         </Switch>
       </div>
      </Router>
    );
   }
   ```
3. Use `history` prop in your `Home.js` file

   ```
   maker(){
      this.props.history.push('/maker');
   }

   designer(){
      this.props.history.push('/designer');
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. It completely worked and solved my issue.

Comment: Happy to help :)